# Add extra packages to NPM from script

Tags: npm, npm-install, yo

I'm building a Yeoman generator which has sub apps. There is a base app which installs base NPM dependencies from a `packages.json` file. I was the sub app to build on this by installing extra dependencies. Currently it does this by running `npm install PACKAGE --save` in the sub app Yeoman script. So, my question is this:

Can NPM install additional dependencies, after the initial `npm install` call, where the deps are defined in a file, like a `myExtraDeps.json` (cf `packages.json`)

Comment: `npm` can't, though you could build a custom script, but that would be hacky.

Comment: OK - thanks for the answer, that's sort of the stage I'd got to.